# Repater: Using C++ property as model

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a C++ property

```
 Q_PROPERTY(QList<qreal> XTickPos MEMBER _xTickPos);
```

which I want to use in a Repeater. In the same QML file, the c++ class has been given the id

```
id: pw
```

The repeater looks like this

```
        Item {
            anchors.fill: parent
            visible: true
            Repeater {
                model: pw.XTickPos.length
                Rectangle{
                    height: 50
                    width: 2
                    x: pw.XTickPos[index]
                    y:10
                    visible: true
                    color: "black"
                    border.width: 2
                }
              }
        }
```

However, nothing is drawn on the screen. If instead I make property in the QML file:

```
 var xTickPos = []
```

and set it via a Q_Invokable function in c++

```
 Q_INVOKABLE QList<qreal> getXTickPositions();
```

and in QML

```
 root.xTickPos=pw.getXTickPositions();
```

and use the QML property xTickPos as model in the above repeater it is working. I checked that pw.XTickPos is correctly filled via a console.log

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use a proper model, that will notify your repeater when elements are added. If QML does not know that something has been added to your list, it wont refresh.

Comment: I thought that if it is a Q_PROPERTY it would automatically send a signal if it changed?

Comment: No. The better syntax for Q_PROPERTY is: `Q_PROPERTY(type name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)` - where you will emit the signal `nameChanged()` in the setter, `setName(...)`. Then you will have a signal emited. But also only if you set a new list - not when you add something to the list. If you look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html you will see that QList does not even have a signal that could notify the length has changed.

Comment: Since the QList won't notify a change of the contained data, it is not advisable to use it as a model (same as the QML/JS Array). Use a http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html instead. You might take a look at the convenient QQmlObjectListModel  you can find here: https://github.com/Cavewhere/lib-qt-qml-tricks

Comment: Regarding performance: Is it costly to use a full model? I am asking because all I need to do is set some (e.g. 10) rectangles, and this needs to be updated fast, e.g. on a window size change. Also: Apart from the notification, why does my above approach not work?

Comment: @numberCruncher it costs like 50 lines of code and about 300 bytes or so bytes for the actual model instance.

Comment: Regarding performance: The overhead to use a full model is mostly due to one layer of indirection and the signals that are sent. Instead of direct access to the QList, you will use special setters and getters that trigger the signals necessary to keep the view up to date.

Comment: That "overhead" is not an issue, since only GUI interacts with data models. And user interaction with the GUI are low bandwidth and high latency.

Answer (score 1):

This one is kinda tricky.

The documentation states that you can use a JS array as a model, and it does state that `QList<qreal>` is automatically converted to a JS array when returned to QML.

But it seems that you can't use a `QList<qreal>` that is automatically converted to a JS array as a model. Go figure...

Naturally, it is preferable to have a proper model with its proper notifications for top efficiency. But in case you really want to go for the list property, it appears you will have to do the conversion manually in a getter:

```
QVariantList model() {
  QVariantList vl;
  for (auto const & v : yourList) vl.append(v);
  return vl;
}
```

Amazingly, although Qt supposedly makes that conversion automatically, it doesn't seem to be able to make a `QVariantList` from a `QList<qreal>`.

That's Qt for you...

Comment: Yes, I picked a QList<qreal> after reading this http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can declare your Q_PROPERTY as CONSTANT if you do not intend to change it. And binding it will not make Qt warns about not having a NOTIFY signal ;)

Comment: @detch, is this missing conversion something new, or has it been like that for long? Since the newer versions, it seems like QML distinguishes between `property var myArray` and `property list<myType> myList` (or something like that) - maybe that messes with the model problems? Can't test it theese days..

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe the conversion doen't kick in when it is a property. Maybe all conversions are not "created equal". Changing the getter to an invokalbe doesn't do the trick either. Qt certainly doesn't cease to surprise :D